# Merge multiple google spreadsheet columns into one column

Tags: merge, google-sheets, compare, match

In a google spreadsheet, I have 2 columns of data. I'd like to merge them into another column. The data on column 1 is not as the same as column 2 (data that is present in column 1 but not in column 2). I would like to merge them to create a single column of information containing no multiple data, complete list of column 1 and 2 to column 3.

Expected Result:

Column 1
Apple
Banana
Cashew
Watermelon

Column 2
Apple
Banana
Strawberry
Mango

Column 3
Apple 
Banana
Cashew
Watermelon
Strawberry
Mango

List of fruits in column 1 and 2 are not exactly the same and it is all listed in column 3 without duplicate fruit name result.

Comment: Can you give example contents of column 1 and column 2, and the corresponding expected result in column 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this formula work as you want in column C:

=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B})

Answer (score -1):

You can use cell function - `CONCATENATE`.

e.g. cell `A1` contains data `"Name"`, cell B1 contains data `"Suffix"` then in `C1` you can use functions as `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` this will give `NAMESuffix` in cell `C1`.